# Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<class-head>' in struct

Tags: c, struct

When I compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
int n, i, total=0;
printf("Enter the number of employees");
scanf("%d", &n);

struct emprecord
{
    int salary, total;
    char name[50];
};
struct emprecord emp[50];
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("Enter the name of employee %d", i+1);
    scanf("%s", &emp[i].name);
    printf("Enter the salary of employee %d", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &emp[i].salary);
    total=total+emp[i].salary;
}
printf("Total salary is: %d", total);
}
```

I get the following errors and I am assuming all will be fixed once the first one is resolved:

> C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(8) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before ''
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(10) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(12) : error C2133: 
>   'emp' : unknown size
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(13) : error C2059: syntax error : 'for'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(13) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing '{' before '<'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(13) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(13) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing '{' before '++'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(13) : error C2059: syntax error : '++'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(13) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(20) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ')' before 'string'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(20) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing '{' before 'string'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(20) : error C2059: syntax error : ''
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(20) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>   C:\Users\shihab130489\Documents\Cpp18888r6u54ru.c(21) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

Can someone please help with the first error? I am unable to understand what the issue is.

Comment: `struct emprecord
{
    int salary, total;
    char name[50];
};
struct emprecord emp[50];` move to before `int n, i, total=0;` see [The end of the description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft C compiler (prior to [VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281705/error-c2143-syntax-error-missing-before-class-head-in-struct/34282212#comment56306935_34282212), it seems) only accepts C89/C90, and that only allows type and variable definitions before any executable statements in a function.  You are trying to declare the structures after some executable statements.  That's valid in C++, and C99 and C11, but not in C90.

Hence:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, total = 0;
    struct emprecord
    {
        int salary, total;
        char name[50];
    };
    struct emprecord emp[50];
    printf("Enter the number of employees");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not read a number successfully\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (n <= 0 || n > 50)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: you entered %d but it should be in the range 1..50\n", n);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of employee %d", i+1);
        if (scanf("%s", &emp[i].name) != 1)
            break;  // Sloppy but effective
        printf("Enter the salary of employee %d", i+1);
        if (scanf("%d", &emp[i].salary) != 1)
            break;  // Sloppy but effective
        total += emp[i].salary;
    }
    printf("Total salary is: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

It's cruel to make people enter names when you're only interested in the salary.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &emp[i].name)` and `scanf("%s", emp[i].name)` works, could you tell why?

Comment: It has support mixed declaration from VS2013. [Supports these ISO C99 language features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @FredrickGauss: both work because the numeric value of the address is the same, but the types are different.  The type of `&emp[i].name` is `char (*)[25]` but the type of `emp[i].name` is `char *`.  Some compilers will warn you of the type mismatch. The difference between the types is evident when you add one to the value: `emp[i].name + 1` is equivalent to `&emp[i].name[1]`, but `&emp[i].name + 1` is equivalent to `&emp[i+1].name`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Thanks for the heads up.  Now to persuade the powers that be at the office that VS2013 or later would be a good idea so we can fix some of the painful code we have to look after that cries out for designated initializers!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to position the struct definition before main.

But, there is no error when I use gcc 4.5.1

Comment: GCC is not MSVC, but the error message is from MSVC and that only accepts C90 — which doesn't allow declarations after executable statements in a block of code.

Comment: Want to see the error in gcc that @JonathanLeffler is talking about?  Add `-std=c90 -pedantic`

Comment: You can also trigger it in C99 or C11 mode with `-Wdeclaration-after-statement`.